# Can you store HDF5 files with GIT

Tags: git, hdf5

Can you store HDF5 files with git? I won't want to version control it, just to keep some data that is around so that I can unit test it. Right now, the files are not coming up when I try to add it to the repository.

Comment: If you could show what you have tried specifically we could likely be more helpful. What do you mean by "the files are not coming up when I try to add ...". Is this a GUI or command line interface?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it should be treated like any other binary. Granted you won't have useful diffing between versions, but storing? sure.

The other question could be the size of the files themselves, but there different solutions (see git [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/)) and I'm not sure it's the point of your question.

Anecdotically, I stumbled upon [these guys](https://gist.github.com/rossant/7b4704e8caeb8f173084) working with HDF5 files on github (unfortunately, they seem not to have HDF5 files stored on the very repo I linked. Still, they could know more, maybe contact them?)

Comment: @ChristopherBell You're welcome. If you finally get a more solid answer than mine, don't shy to come document it here, it could be useful to others. And until then ... tick accept on the *best so far* answer ;-)